# Custom multipart-form-data serializable in Kotlin/Ktor

Tags: kotlin, multipartform-data, ktor

Does anyone know how to program the override function `convertForReceive` of a custom `Multipart.FormData` converter?

I want to convert the multipart request to my class with the converter but I don't know how it works.

I have:

**Application.kt**

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json()
    register(ContentType.MultiPart.FormData, CustomMultipartConverter)
}
```

**CustomMultipartConverter**

```
object CustomMultipartConverter: ContentConverter {

    override suspend fun convertForReceive(context: PipelineContext<ApplicationReceiveRequest, ApplicationCall>): Any? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override suspend fun convertForSend(
        context: PipelineContext<Any, ApplicationCall>,
        contentType: ContentType,
        value: Any
    ): Any? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

**REQUEST CLASS**

```
class CreatePostRequest(
   val text: String,
   val image: File? = null
)
```

**ROUTE**

```
route("v1/posts") {
    authenticate {
        route("create") {
            val authJWT = call.authentication.principal as JWTAtuh
            val request = call.receive<CreatePostRequest>()
            //myCode
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take [`SerializationConverter`](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/c96b3e14c0fcea51490200ee726628f06aa89800/ktor-features/ktor-serialization/jvm/src/io/ktor/serialization/SerializationConverter.kt#L58) as a reference:

```
override suspend fun convertForReceive(context: PipelineContext<ApplicationReceiveRequest, ApplicationCall>): Any? {
    val request = context.subject
    val channel = request.value as? ByteReadChannel ?: return null
    val charset = context.call.request.contentCharset() ?: defaultCharset

    val serializer = format.serializersModule.serializer(request.typeInfo)
    val contentPacket = channel.readRemaining()

    return when (format) {
        is StringFormat -> format.decodeFromString(serializer, contentPacket.readText(charset))
        is BinaryFormat -> format.decodeFromByteArray(serializer, contentPacket.readBytes())
        else -> {
            contentPacket.discard()
            error("Unsupported format $format")
        }
    }
}
```